# Symfony firewall error using profile matcher

Tags: symfony, toolbar, firewall, matcher

I'm currently stuck using profiler for production usage. Therefore I've followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/matchers.html) tutorial but using additional to the role an cookie.
I've getting an 500:hphp invoke error for the web developer toolbar:

http://localhost:8000/app.php/_wdt/d379e0

Here is my config:

**routing.yml**

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

I've moved this two rules from routing_dev.yml to routing.yml

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Fairbaer\SecurityBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 13

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        administrators:
            id: security_user_provider
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                username_parameter: "login[username]"
                password_parameter: "login[password]"
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
            remember_me:
                lifetime: 31536000
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
                key:   "%secret%" # 2.7
                # secret:   "%secret%" # 2.8-dev
                remember_me_parameter: "login[remember_me]"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

as you can see my security.yml is straight forward to the tutorials [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html).

**config_prod.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

#framework:
#    validation:
#        cache: apc

#doctrine:
#    orm:
#        metadata_cache_driver: apc
#        result_cache_driver: apc
#        query_cache_driver: apc

framework:
    profiler:
        only_exceptions: false
        matcher:
            service: app.admin_profiler_cookie_matcher

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

Here i've registered my matcher (which works great) and activate the web developer toolbar.

Finally [here](http://pastebin.com/c2QZGKUZ) is the log message

Comment: You moved `_profiler` and `_wdt` routes to `routing.yml` but did you enable `WebProfilerBundle` in prod environment in your AppKernel.php?

Comment: Have you checked your cookie contents which is being sent with the http request to profiler url via chrome developer tools etc?

Comment: Jep, WebProfilerBundle is moved to prod environment... If i disable the firewall completely it works as intended, also the cookie witch is set works as intended